# how to fix Code Analysis warnings

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I have a code

```
public String makeHttpGetRequest(String url)
        {
            try
            {
                string responce = string.Empty;
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;


                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    responce = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                return responce;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Internet Connection error" + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

And i am getting a warning when i run code analysis in Visual studio that

**CA2202    Do not dispose objects multiple times   Object 'stream' can be disposed more than once in method 'InformationIO.makeHttpGetRequest(string)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.: Lines: 244  InformationIO.cs    244**

line 224 refers to line 13 here the closing bracket before **return responce;**

How can i fix this warning.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines reference the same `stream`, and will try to dispose it twice:

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
```

Remove the second `using` block (of the three you have), as it's unnecessary in this case.

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream());
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        responce = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

If you want to be *really* sure the stream is disposed, add a `finally` block:

```
Stream stream = null;
try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        stream = response.GetResponseStream());
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            responce = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    // check if stream is not null (although it should be), and dispose of it
    if (stream != null)
        stream.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The StreamReader object calls Dispose() on the provided Stream object
>   when StreamReader.Dispose is called.

This means StreamReader will call Dispose on Stream object and your using statement will do so as well. Alternative could be:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
       responce = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
return responce;
```

Answer (score 0):

The deeper issue here is that the design of `StreamReader` is incorrect; it should never dispose the underlying stream because it doesn't *own* it.

The following pattern is pretty common:

```
public class Foo: IDisposable
{
    public Foo(Bar bar) {...}
}

public class Bar: IDisposable { ... }
```

When disposing `foo`, it should never dispose `bar` automatically for you, because it does not own `bar`; `bar` is an object supplied by the user of `foo`; its therefore responsability of the user to take care of `bar`.

This is essentially what is happening in your code; you are correctly taking care of `stream` but `StreamReader` is also taking care of something that is not really its business, disposing `stream` for you too.

So, to wrap up: Your code is correct. Due to a design flaw in `StreamReader` your correct code is creating an issue that needs to be taken care of; duplicate calls to `Dispose()`.

Other answers point out good ways to fix the issue, so I wont duplicate code here.